# Robotframework Change testcase name with variable

Tags: robotframework

Is there any possible to change testcase name with variable like below?

(I don't want to change name from python side)

```
*** Variables ***
${country}  US

*** Test Cases ***
test_${country}
```

Comment: Would you by any chance mean keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it isn't possible to  use a variable inside a test case name. It follows the same logic as normal Python functions, so normally, it isn't possible.

Instead, you can use the variable in the setup or in the test case directly to modify it's behaviour.

If you want to generate test cases based on a variable, you can write a (python) script that can generate the needed file/test cases with the corresponding values. Or, even better, use an Model-Based Testing tool to produce them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The way you have shown it should work. Are you facing any issue with that? If yes, pls provide the detailed error.

Comment: I just realized that this depends on your version. Support for variable in test case name was introduced in version v3.2b1 released in Jan 2020. Just update your version to latest and you should have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is supported.

example:-

*** Test Cases ***

Test title ${name}

```
[Tags]    DEBUG

Log  Welcome ${name}
```

output:-

robot --variable name:sample eg.robot

[image]